# reading scanner barcode Through camera on android

Tags: android

i have this code for scanning barcode Through camera on android

```
btnBarcode = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.btnBAR);
btnBarcode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                intent.setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android");
                intent.putExtra("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN.SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
                try 
                {
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

        }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

the scanner is open, but how to insert the reading to any String Variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override onActivityResult() as explained in this [piece of documentation](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent).